# Why is the array reset?

Tags: php

I'm using [PocketMine](https://github.com/PocketMine/PocketMine-MP) to write a class for a minigame server I'm creating, but I don't think that should make a difference in my question. I have this array `$alive` which should contain the contents of `$players` when `start()` is called. When the function `onDeath()` is called, the array prints out empty.

Why is this?

```
namespace minigames\games;

use pocketmine\event\player\PlayerDeathEvent;
use pocketmine\event\Listener;
use minigames\BaseGame;
use pocketmine\level\Position;

class Infected implements Listener, BaseGame
{
    private $alive = [];

    private $plugin;
    private $spawn;
    private $level;

    public function __construct($plugin)
    {
        $this->plugin = $plugin;
        $this->level = $this->plugin->getServer()->getLevelByName("infected");
        $this->spawn = new Position(133, 4,  128, $this->level);
    }

    public function start($players)
    {
        $this->alive = $players;
        foreach($players as $p)
        {
        $p->teleport($this->spawn);
        }
        $this->plugin->getServer()->getLogger()->info(var_dump($this->alive)); //prints out array with contents the same as $players
    }

    public function onDeath(PlayerDeathEvent $event)
    {
        $this->plugin->getServer()->getLogger()->info(var_dump($this->alive)); //array is empty
    }

    public function stop($winner)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this? There's nothing here to keep the value of `$alive` if you're making calls to this on different pages

Comment: @andrewsi `$alive` is stored as the private variable to be accessed within the same class

Comment: Either the methods are called on two separate objects or you never called `start()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this just to check

```
<?php
class Infected
{
    private $alive = [];

    public function start($players)
    {
        $this->alive = $players;
        var_dump($this->alive);
    }

    public function onDeath()
    {
        var_dump($this->alive);
    }
}

$infected = new Infected();
$infected->start(['a', 'b']);
$infected->onDeath();
```

It returns this which is correct

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
```

I am afraid that you are using different objects.

Comment: You took out the `foreach`.

Comment: The `foreach` has no effect on `$this->alive`.

Comment: Right, but your answer does not show or prove that. It proves facts about some other code that does something else.